# tv unable to playback ffmpeg converted media

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to convert some raw video camerafiles using the following ffmpeg commmand. after conversion the pc plays back the files without any problem. also the phone plays it back using vlc. but the tv gives unsupported format. the tv plays back all files even h265 but only this file it gives an error. any help is appreciated:

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mov -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -strict -2 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -threads 0 converted/1.mp4
```

and this is the ffmpeg info of the original file:

```
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg/target --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg/target/inclu     de -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg/target/lib -lm -static' --extra-version=Xtrea     m-Codes --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --disable-debug --disable-shared --enable-libx2     65 --enable-static --extra-cflags=--static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-     doc --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libass --enable-gray --enab     le-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libthe     ora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --e     nable-version3 --enable-libvpx --enable-libxavs --disable-devices --enable-librtmp --extr     a-libs='-lrtmp -lnettle -lhogweed -lgmp -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lc -ldl'
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 28.100 / 56. 28.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 12.100 /  5. 12.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2017-05-18 07:39:04
  Duration: 00:10:38.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 239010 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 2     36756 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 5k tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-05-18 07:39:04
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 44100 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit     ), 2116 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-05-18 07:39:04
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-05-18 07:39:04
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
At least one output file must be specified
```

After conversion i get like 1.mp4,2.mp4,3.mp4... then I concat them using concat command to one file. all went ok without any problem but the tv does not support the file.

I found out it is encoded with apple prores so I googled some conversion commands but they also did not seem to help like this:

```
yuv422p, lossless audio
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -pix_fmt "yuv422p" -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -qp 0 -acodec pcm_s16le "output_yuv422p.mkv"

yuv422p, aac audio
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -pix_fmt "yuv422p" -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -qp 0 -acodec -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 256K "output_yuv422p.mp4"
```

Comment: The TV will probably require `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Comment: Yep. That was it! it works! Thanks you saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TV requires the output option `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`), because the vast majority of non-FFmpeg based players can't decode H.264 video that does not use YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.